# How to split number in image(OCR)?

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I want to recognize the numbers in image,the numbers are not placed in a line and have some "noise" ,such as the below images (just a part of my data):
I have searched some project  and  papers ,but did not find a good way to solve the problem,Who can give me some tips that how can I solve the problem or what paper is useful for me?
Thanks!!!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If segmentation is difficult, then simply avoid it. Handwriting recognition faces the same problem: how would you segment this image (source: IAM dataset) into characters?

[image]

End-to-end trainable neural networks (NN) are able to recognize text in such images.
These NNs are trained with pairs of images and ground-truth texts. You don't have to do any segmentation and you also don't have to specify the character positions.

Here is an illustration how such a neural network for text recognition may look (implementation see https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR).
[image]

It contains CNN layers, RNN layers and a final CTC layer. This CTC layer is the ingredient which enables training in a segmentation-free manner.

I don't want to repeat myself too much, have a look at this article to get an understanding of how such a NN looks like and how it works: https://towardsdatascience.com/2326a3487cd5

And read this paper for a more in-depth discussion and for further references: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05717.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Now I have given up the segmentation,I know little about deep learning,but I know it is a best way for me to solve the problem,appreciated for the resources you gave!